# Ember-cli: New project without Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am creating a new project by issuing the following command:

```
ember new todomvc
```

The problem is that the new project does not have HandleBars loaded. This is what I see in the console:

```
ember.debug.js:4888 DEBUG: Ember      : 1.12.0
ember.debug.js:4888 DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.17
ember.debug.js:4888 DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
```

Any ideas why? How can I load handlebars from an ember-cli created project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Version 1.10, ember is dependent on HTMLBars. You can read more [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html)

Comment: Thanks, Akis. Can I still create hbs files and expect them to be used by Ember as templates?

Comment: Yes of course. But you should get more familiar also to htmlbars new syntax which is much cleaner!